# How to add widget to Windows 10 taskbar

Tags: windows-10

I'm not sure if this is the right site to be asking this. I have a program I made for Windows that essentially searches for and opens a folder via the file explorer. Right now, it's just a normal .exe that the user has pinned to their taskbar and will open a UI. I want to somehow program it so the user can install it and have it as a permanent widget on their taskbar, but I can't find any documentation or anything for adding anything to the taskbar. Is there any way to accomplish this or good resource I can study to figure this out?

Comment: Right click the .exe and select "Pin to Taskbar"

Comment: That's what I currently have people doing, I want to make a UI that is on the taskbar, not a shortcut that opens a separate window

Comment: Looking for a way to do this as well. Like how Windows show weather info in the right side of the taskbar: https://i.imgur.com/U11us7g.png or like what this plugin does https://github.com/zhongyang219/TrafficMonitor